# Do scripts executed remotely via SQLCMD get processed by the host or target machine?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

When running a command like the following:

```
SQLCMD -S MYREMOTECOMPUTER\DB -E -i CreateDBCompany.sql
```

Does the CPU of the host or target machine get used to execute the bits within `CreateDbCompany.sql`?

**Context**

I have a host machine that's copied a BAK to a remote machine.  I'd like to also trigger the restore of the BAK remotely, but not if it consumes network resources (by using the host machine to actually execute the restoration - effectively doing a remote restore) as I'll be triggering ~20 of these simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you doubt on which server the command will be executed you can try different things like running Profiler against remote server or do some debugging. The easies way to be sure is to run following script:

```
SQLCMD -S MYREMOTECOMPUTER\DB -E -q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"
```